# как сохранять сообщение aiogram

Tags: python-3.x, aiogram

я сделал бот на библиотеке aiogram без бд, и мне надо придумать как сделать так чтобы после команды /kp введённые человеком данные(последние сообщение после команды) сохранялись в переменную и отправлялись в мой канал, либо без сохранения в переменную сразу отправлялись в мой канал, кто знает как это сделать, помогите пожалуйста заранее спасибо

Comment: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/9l56oT9i9ntgtw готовый бот, которого я закинул в архив.
Он пересылает все сообщения, которые пишут ему, для того, кого укажешь админом
в файлике конфиг (пишешь апи бота и айди админа, себя например)

Answer (score 0):

Обрабатывать прошлые сообщения **нельзя**, только новые. Конечно ты можешь хранить в бд каждое пришедшее сообщения и ждать пока пользователь напишет твою команду, а потом отправлять. А эта функция отправляет каждое пришедшее сообщение в канал который тебе нужен.

```py
@dp.message_handler(sand_message, content_types=["text"])
async def sand_message(message: types.Message):
    bot_chat_id = message.chat.id
    group_id = # id группы в которую должны приходить сообщения
    if bot_chat_id != group_id:
        await bot.forward_message(group_id, bot_chat_id, message.message_id)message.message_id)
```

Comment: мне надо з бота в группу пересылать, точнее даже з бота в канал, у бота же вроде нету id?

Comment: @RomanSinrsk Я изменил код сверху, теперь любое текстовое сообщение которое приходит боту, будет отправляться в группу id которой ты укажешь.

Comment: спасибо огромное